# Convert scipy docstrings (reST) to HTML using docutils

Tags: python, html, restructuredtext, docstring, docutils

I'm designing a filter design GUI and would like to display docstrings from Python's scipy.signal in a QTextBrowser, requiring HTML format. I think docutils should do the job for me and I tried

```
from docutils.core import publish_string
from scipy.signal import remez
self.txtFiltInfoBox.append(publish_string(remez.__doc__,
          writer_name='html'))
```

where txtFiltInfoBox is a QTextBrowser instance. However, publish_string chokes on the first heading ("Parameters") it encounters in the docstring:

```
docutils.utils.SystemMessage: <string>:10: (SEVERE/4) Unexpected section title.

Parameters
----------
```

I think the reason is that the method's whole docstring is indented, leading to an invalid reST markup. Is there an easy way to dedent the docstring or to tell publish_string to ignore a certain number of leading blanks?

The full code can be found at [pyFDA project](https://github.com/chipmuenk/pyFDA/blob/master/pyFDA/input_widgets/input_info.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to, as the docs put it:

> Remove any common leading whitespace from every line in *text*.

For example (from [a similar question on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60366/32391)):

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print(textwrap.dedent(
        """
        Usage examples:
        Test deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] test deploy
        Staging deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] staging deploy
        Production deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] production deploy
        """
))

Usage examples:
Test deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] test deploy
Staging deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] staging deploy
Production deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] production deploy
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really great! Yet another Python module I didn't know ... and sorry haven't got enough reputation to vote you up.